# Typescript error on ant design version 3.0 form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm getting a typescript error when trying out the `Form.create` from https://ant.design/components/form/

This is the error:
[image]

**Edit**
When I try to use this form:
[image]

```
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
          })(
            <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
            initialValue: true,
          })(
            <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
          )}
          <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">Forgot password</a>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
            Log in
          </Button>
          Or <a href="">register now!</a>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create()(NormalLoginForm);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, mountNode);
```

I get the typescript error here:
`Form.create()(NormalLoginForm)`

Answer (score 4):

Form.create is a static function that try to cast your **NormalLoginForm** component props  to **FormComponentProps**. So to achieve it you can create your prop interface **NormalLoginProps** and import **FormComponentProps** from 'antd/lib/form/Form' directly.

```
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import {FormComponentProps} from 'antd/lib/form/Form';
const FormItem = Form.Item;
interface NormalLoginProps{}

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component<NormalLoginProps & FormComponentProps> {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
          })(
            <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
            initialValue: true,
          })(
            <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
          )}
          <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">Forgot password</a>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
            Log in
          </Button>
          Or <a href="">register now!</a>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create<NormalLoginProps>()(NormalLoginForm);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, mountNode);
```